# Passing in a result of a function to generate readme

Tags: javascript, node.js, readme

Bootcamp student here. I seem to be having trouble passing in the result of function renderBadge(license) to the generateREADME function. I am using inquirer to grab inputs, and generate a readme. The functions renderBadge() and licenseLink() is solely pertaining to license portion of the inquirer. However, I can't seem to pass this info along and display it to the generating function. Is there a way to do this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Upon function execution, the ${badge} seems to be undefined.
[image: Result of execution]

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const fs = require("fs");

const generateREADME = ({ title, description, installation, usage, contributions, tests, license, github, email, badge,}) =>

    `# ${title} 
    ${badge}
    
    ## Description

    ${description}

    (Rest of Readme Generation here)
    `

inquirer
    .prompt([
        { 
            (other prompts here)
        },
        {
            type: "list",
            name: "license",
            message: "What license is your project?",
            choices: [
            "Apache 2.0",
            "Boost",
            "GNU AGPL v3",
            "MIT",
            "Perl",
            "other",
            ],
            validate: (licenseInput) => {
            if (licenseInput) {
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log(`Please enter your project's license!`);
                return false;
            }
            },
        }
    ])
    .then((answers) => {
      const readmePageContent = generateREADME(answers);
      renderBadge(answers)

        fs.writeFile('README.md', readmePageContent, (err) => {
            err ? console.log(err) : console.log('Successfully generated README!')
        })
    })

    function renderBadge(license) {
        let badge = ''
        if (license === 'Apache 2.0') {
            badge = `![License](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Apache_2.0-blue.svg)]`
        } else if (license === 'Boost') {
            badge = `![License](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Boost_1.0-lightblue.svg)]`
        } else if (license === 'GNU APGL v3') {
            badge = `![License: AGPL v3](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-AGPL_v3-blue.svg)]`
        } else if (license === 'MIT') {
            badge = `![License: MIT](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-MIT-yellow.svg)]`
        } else if (license === 'Perl') {
            badge = `![License: Artistic-2.0](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Perl-0298c3.svg)]`
        } else {
            badge = ''
        }
        return badge;
        generateREADME(badge)
    }
```

Comment: Nobody should have to read all that code, please devise a minimal example, which may also help you pinpoint the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is the way you pass/accept arguments.

`answers` is an object containing the key/value-pairs an example could be:

```
const answers = {
  title: "Hello World",
  description: "Hello World, this is a test description",
  // ...
  license: "GNU AGPL v3",
};
```

You then pass the `answers` object to `renderBadge`.

```
renderBadge(answers)
```

However in `renderBadge` you expect `license` as the sole argument.

```
function renderBadge(license) {
  // ...
}
```

Since you passed the whole `answers` object, that is what you will receive. Meaning that the `licence` parameter will contain the `answers` object.

To fix this you should pass just the license to `renderBadge`, not all the answers. So use `renderBadge(answers.license)` instead.

Alternatively you could also use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) like you did in `generateREADME`, and define `renderBadge` as:

```
function renderBadge({ license }) {
  // ...
}
```

If you choose to use object destructuring, you should still pass the full answers object to `renderBadge`, so `renderBadge(answers)`.

---

The second, non-essential mistake is:

```
return badge;
generateREADME(badge) // never executed
```

The line after the return is never executed. This doesn't really break anything, since you didn't need that line anyways, so it can just be removed.

---

Lastly, and probably most importantly the order of the following lines are incorrect.

```
const readmePageContent = generateREADME(answers);
renderBadge(answers.license) // after the first fix
```

The `renderBadge()` call should be made before you render the readme file, the resulting contents should then be passed as argument to `generateREADME()`.

```
const badge = renderBadge(answers.license);
const readmePageContent = generateREADME({ ...answers, badge });
```

This uses the [spread syntax in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) combined with the [property definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) to pass a single object, containing al the required arguments.

---

So the final result might look like this (with minimum changes):

```
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const fs = require("fs");

const generateREADME = ({title, description, installation, usage, contributions, tests, license, github, email, badge,}) => (
    `# ${title} 
    ${badge}
    
    ## Description

    ${description}

    (Rest of Readme Generation here)
    `
);

inquirer.prompt([
    { 
        (other prompts here)
    },
    {
        type: "list",
        name: "license",
        message: "What license is your project?",
        choices: [
            "Apache 2.0",
            "Boost",
            "GNU AGPL v3",
            "MIT",
            "Perl",
            "other",
        ],
        validate: (licenseInput) => {
            if (licenseInput) {
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log(`Please enter your project's license!`);
                return false;
            }
        },
    }
]).then((answers) => {
    const badge = renderBadge(answers.license); // pass only the license, not all the anwers
    const readmePageContent = generateREADME({ ...answers, badge }); // pass the answers combined with the badge

    fs.writeFile('README.md', readmePageContent, (err) => {
        err ? console.log(err) : console.log('Successfully generated README!')
    })
});

function renderBadge(license) {
    let badge = ''
    if (license === 'Apache 2.0') {
        badge = `![License](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Apache_2.0-blue.svg)]`
    } else if (license === 'Boost') {
        badge = `![License](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Boost_1.0-lightblue.svg)]`
    } else if (license === 'GNU APGL v3') {
        badge = `![License: AGPL v3](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-AGPL_v3-blue.svg)]`
    } else if (license === 'MIT') {
        badge = `![License: MIT](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-MIT-yellow.svg)]`
    } else if (license === 'Perl') {
        badge = `![License: Artistic-2.0](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Perl-0298c3.svg)]`
    } else {
        badge = ''
    }
    return badge; // removal of generateREADME
}
```